# Trying to be able to dereference a void pointer to a user defined type aside from system type

Tags: c#, pointers

- I need to be able to dereference a void pointer for the purposes of a telegram type system for use in my game I'm developing. The reason for a void pointer is that I need a way to be able to pass a user defined type or system type that is extra data (any type of data so I don't have to build multiple functions) into the function that sends the message to other components in my game.
- The reason that I'm using a telegram system is to keep game components single minded but being able to tell each other about stuff they may need to do by sending an enum message type and data that pertains to that message type.
- Since my game is a card game I'll give some examples why I'm trying to do this:
- Example1: A card is played that needs to deal 2 damage to the target selected, so it would message the target with TakeDamage (enum message type) and the value of 2.
- Example2: A card is played that gives its target a new ability, so it would message the target with AddAbility (enum message type) and the ability to add (which would be a class containing how the ability reacts and what not).
- Also to ask, is there a different way to do this without using a void pointer if I can't do this with a void pointer?

Comment: how can you dereference a void pointer? How many bytes is a `void`?

Comment: From what I've read you can dereference a void pointer by casting it to a system type pointer then dereference that. Example being a void pointer to a double. You'd cast the void pointer to a double pointer then use the dereference operator and get the value.

Comment: If you've read about void pointers, then you're not really reading about C#. How about passing an `object` instead? What do you plan to _do_ with the pointer once you've dereferenced it?

Comment: Well I'm still new to C# and the keywords and what they can and can't do. What I was going to do with the pointer after dereferencing it was grab the extra info that its pointing to and with whatever recieved the message would do what it has to with it based on the message sent.

Comment: Ok after reading about object in C# I think I can do what I need to with that rather than a void pointer.

Answer (score 0):

OK. After reading into object and doing a small test program using my messaging system I can use object instead of a void pointer. When I asked this question I didn't know about object (still new to C#).